# Function to print a 2d array centred around an element x

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array

I have this array that I want to print, it is a `8x10` array but I want to print it as a `5x5` array centred around an element `x`.

For example

```
char array[8][7] = {['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h']
['q','w','e','r','t','y','u','i']
['k','j','h','g','f','d','s','a']
['z','x','c','v','b','n','m','q']
['g','z','p','l','k','h','n','a']
['q','e','m','a','c','t','u','p']
['r','b','l','t','k','f','b','z']}

i = 5 j = 2 
for(k = 0; k < 5; k++) 
{ 
    for(j = 0; j < 5; j++) 
    { 
        print("%c",array[i][j]); 
    }    
    printf("\n"); 
    
}
```

I have tried this, and it is giving me 2 to the left and 2 to the right but its printing it 5 times, and its not printing the 2 above and below.

If I want to print a `5x5` array with the centre of the array being m ([6][3]) how would I do that

OUTPUT:

```
ema
ema
ema
ema
ema
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Don't forget that arrays in C are indexed from zero?

Comment: so I have tried this, and its giving me 2 to the left and 2 to the right but its printing it 5 times, and its not printing the 2 above and below, 

where i = 5 and j = 2


for(k = 0; k < 5; k++)
        {
            for(j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                print("%c",array[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }

Comment: Add it to your question where you can format the code.

Comment: Do you know how to print the whole array?  By having `i` run from 0 to N-1, and `j` run from 0 to M-1, and printing `array[i][j]`?  (Where N and M are the sizes of the whole array, of course.)  So if you want to print your 5×5 subarray centered on element `x,y`, it seems to me you will want to have `i` run from `x-2` to `x+2`, and `j` run from `y-2` to `y+2`.  But for a robust program you will also have to double check to make sure `i` never gets less than 0 or greater than N-1, and you will have to make sure `j` never gets less than 0 or greater than M-1.

Comment: Yeah, I can print the whole array, but every time I go to do the x+2 x-2,  and the y-2 y+2, bounds checking is giving me seg faults

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible implementation that also performs proper bounds checking (hopefully, I haven't tested it a lot). You can try it out [here](https://godbolt.org/z/W7bTa1o9b):

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int min(int x, int y) { return x < y ? x : y; }
int max(int x, int y) { return x > y ? x : y; }

void print_5(int at_y, int at_x, char *array, int dim_y, int dim_x) {
    int from_y = max(0, at_y - 2);
    int to_y = min(at_y + 2, dim_y - 1);

    int from_x = max(0, at_x - 2);
    int to_x = min(at_x + 2, dim_x - 1);

    for(int y = from_y; y <= to_y; y++) {
        for(int x = from_x; x <= to_x; x++)
            printf("%c", array[x + y * dim_x]);
        printf("\n");
    }

}

int main() {
    char array[7][8] = {
        {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h'},
        {'q','w','e','r','t','y','u','i'},
        {'k','j','h','g','f','d','s','a'},
        {'z','x','c','v','b','n','m','q'},
        {'g','z','p','l','k','h','n','a'},
        {'q','e','m','a','c','t','u','p'},
        {'r','b','l','t','k','f','b','z'},
    };

    print_5(5, 2, (char*)array, 7, 8);
}
```

Regarding `array[x + y * dim_x]`. First, keep in mind that arrays start at `0`. Therefore, if you want it centred around the ‘m’ close to the bottom left corner, that would be at index `array[5][2]`. Secondly, The first dimension of a two-dimensional array `int[y][x]` is the rows ('y'), the second is the columns ('x'). In memory, the rows are simply stored after one another, that is

```c
int array[4][2] = {
    {1, 2},
    {3, 4},
    {5, 6},
    {7, 8}
};
```

is [the same as](https://godbolt.org/z/chj735GhT)

```c
int array[8] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
```

Therefore, the formula for the index of the element in the `n`-th column of the `m`-th row is `n + m * number_of_columns` (where `number_of_columns` = `dim_x` above).

Because an array in C (at least when passed to a function) is just a pointer to a block of memory, we need to pass the y and x dimensions of the array to the function. Also, normally, you would define constants for the dimensions and use those throughout the code instead of integer literals, but the function above is supposed to be only a simple implementation.

Also, as a side note, array literals in C use `{}` and not `[]` :)

Answer (score 0):

The code in the question doesn't compile, and appears to show a variety of misunderstandings.  For example:

```c
char array[8][7] = {['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h']
['q','w','e','r','t','y','u','i']
['k','j','h','g','f','d','s','a']
['z','x','c','v','b','n','m','q']
['g','z','p','l','k','h','n','a']
['q','e','m','a','c','t','u','p']
['r','b','l','t','k','f','b','z']}
```

The square brackets should be curly brackets and the close brackets should be followed by a comma.  There needs to be a semicolon at the end of the definition.  There are 7 rows of data with 8 elements in each row, so the array dimension should be `array[7][8]`.   The question text mentions an 8x10 array; it doesn't show that.

The question also says (more or less) *"I want to print a 5x5 array with the centre of the array being `'m'` (element `array[6][3]`)"* — but there is one `'m'` at `array[3][6]` and another at `array[6][2]`.  For both of those locations, a 5x5 array centred on those locations runs outside the bounds of the array.  The code should avoid such access.

C99 and later has support for variable-length arrays (unconditionally in C99; conditionally in C11 or C17).  That should be used in modern code unless you suffer from a compiler that does not support it.  Compilers on the major desktop Unix-based systems do support them (GCC, Clang, …).

Here is some code that seems to work:

```c
/* SO 6908-1666 */

#include <stdio.h>

static void print_submatrix(int nrows, int ncols, char matrix[nrows][ncols],
                            int crow, int ccol, int rsize, int csize)
{
    int min_row = crow - (rsize / 2);
    int max_row = min_row + rsize;
    int min_col = ccol - (csize / 2);
    int max_col = min_col + csize;

    /* Array bounds? */
    if (min_col < 0)
        min_col = 0;
    if (min_row < 0)
        min_row = 0;
    if (max_col > ncols)
        max_col = ncols;
    if (max_row > nrows)
        max_row = nrows;

    printf("R = %d, C = %d, Centre (%d, %d), Size (%d, %d) ",
            nrows, ncols, crow, ccol, rsize, csize);
    printf("Columns [%d..%d), Rows [%d..%d)\n", min_col, max_col, min_row, max_row);
    for (int i = min_row; i < max_row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = min_col; j < max_col; j++)
            putchar(matrix[i][j]);
        putchar('\n');
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char array[7][8] =
    {
        { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h' },
        { 'q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'y', 'u', 'i' },
        { 'k', 'j', 'h', 'g', 'f', 'd', 's', 'a' },
        { 'z', 'x', 'c', 'v', 'b', 'n', 'm', 'q' },
        { 'g', 'z', 'p', 'l', 'k', 'h', 'n', 'a' },
        { 'q', 'e', 'm', 'a', 'c', 't', 'u', 'p' },
        { 'r', 'b', 'l', 't', 'k', 'f', 'b', 'z' },
    };

    print_submatrix(7, 8, array, 6, 2, 5, 5);
    print_submatrix(7, 8, array, 3, 6, 5, 5);
    print_submatrix(7, 8, array, 3, 3, 5, 5);
    /* Print whole matrix, but it isn't a good use of the interface */
    print_submatrix(7, 8, array, 3, 4, 7, 8);

    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
R = 7, C = 8, Centre (6, 2), Size (5, 5) Columns [0..5), Rows [4..7)
gzplk
qemac
rbltk
R = 7, C = 8, Centre (3, 6), Size (5, 5) Columns [4..8), Rows [1..6)
tyui
fdsa
bnmq
khna
ctup
R = 7, C = 8, Centre (3, 3), Size (5, 5) Columns [1..6), Rows [1..6)
werty
jhgfd
xcvbn
zplkh
emact
R = 7, C = 8, Centre (3, 4), Size (7, 8) Columns [0..8), Rows [0..7)
abcdefgh
qwertyui
kjhgfdsa
zxcvbnmq
gzplkhna
qemactup
rbltkfbz
```